# Mongodb: add field at projection

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I do project my collection and response is

```
{$project: {     
    BusinessCode: {$substrCP : ["$Payload", {$sum : ["$start",15]},{$subtract : [{$subtract : ["$end", "$start"]}, 18]}]}}
}
```

response:

`{
    "_id" : UUID("e3c966cd-cf45-4e42-9a0c-c1d49dcd6c4c"),
    "BusinessCode" : "8-4-208696-14-1-0-0"
}`:

Now I want to split BusinessCode and put the first char into other field that does not exist.with this command I can do that:

```
{$project: {
    BusinessCode:1 ,
     Domain : {$ifNull:[ "$Domain", { $arrayElemAt: [ { $split : ["$BusinessCode", "-"] },0]}]}}
 }
```

at this time my query is :

```
{$project: {     
    BusinessCode: {$substrCP : ["$Payload", {$sum : ["$start",15]},{$subtract : [{$subtract : ["$end", "$start"]}, 18]}]}}
},
{$project: {
    BusinessCode:1 ,
     Domain : {$ifNull:[ "$Domain", { $arrayElemAt: [ { $split : ["$BusinessCode", "-"] },0]}]}}
 }
```

and its response :

```
{
    "_id" : UUID("e3c966cd-cf45-4e42-9a0c-c1d49dcd6c4c"),
    "BusinessCode" : "8-4-208696-14-1-0-0",
    "Domain" : "8"
}
```

I think, it is not good that I have two separated project but how could I put these two projection into one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`$let`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/) operator.

```
{"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":{
  "$let":{
    "vars":{
      "code":{"$substrCP":["$Payload",{"$sum":["$start",15]},{"$subtract":[{"$subtract":["$end","$start"]},18]}]}
    },
    "in":{
      "BusinessCode":"$$code",
      "Domain":{"$ifNull":["$Domain",{"$arrayElemAt":[{"$split":["$$code","-"]},0]}]}
    }
  }
}}}
```

Comment: this is complete code https://paste.ubuntu.com/26535767/. when i run this code I got error: https://paste.ubuntu.com/26535781/  . I am using mongodb 3.6. @veeram

Comment: Sorry I meant to use `$replaceRoot` not  `$project`.

Comment: this is my out put :`{
    "BusinessCode" : "8-4-208696-14-1-0-0",
    "Domain" : null
}`

Comment: Sorry again.Updated answer. Missing extra $ for code variable.